# Django programming - how to redirect to original url

Tags: python, django

I have a website **www.example.com** with many pages.

On each page I put one special unique button, which link to unique URL **www.example.com/task1**.

Once click this button, Django urls patten will pass it to dedicated function **task1** for me.

My question is how to refresh original URL after completion of the task1, I find **request.path** only could transfer **/task1**. Any idea to get back the URL which the button allocated. Please refer to my task1 function.

```
def task1(request):
    '''
    do  task1  job
    '''
    return render(request, request.path)  
    # above return could not render the original URL which I clicked from.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the link to your task1 function, include the current URL as a query string:

```html
<a href="task1/?next={{ request.get_full_path }}">Task 1</a>
```

Then in the view:

```python
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def task1(request):
    # Do task 1...
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    if next:
        return redirect(next)
    # some fallback here…
```

---

For completeness, and based on @Alasdair's comments, you can mimic what Django does to ensure that the redirect URL is safe:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils.http import url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme


def task1(request):
    # Do task 1...
    pass

    # Return the user-originating redirect URL if it's safe.
    redirect_to = request.GET.get("next")
    url_is_safe = url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme(
        url=redirect_to,
        allowed_hosts=settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS,
        require_https=request.is_secure(),
    )
    if url_is_safe and redirect_to:
        return redirect(redirect_to)
    return redirect("http://www.example.com")
```

For the original see https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L68, though that's a class-based view, rather than a function-based view as you have here.

---

In a bid to future-proof this answer for a while longer:

1. Read the comments below; @mlissner is talking sense, for example, regarding the renaming of this in Django 3+,
2. Know that there are security implications with acting on user input, even from a query string and GET request, and if you're not writing to the database.

Comment: It isn't safe to trust a url from the GET parameters and redirect to it. It can cause your users to be redirected to malicious domains. If you look at Django's login view for example, it uses `is_safe_url`.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair. I've updated it with an option to mimic that.

Comment: This is still not safe. `is_safe_url` has [been renamed in Django 3 (see last bullet)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#id3). On top of using the new function, `url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme`, you should also be sure to encode your URL with the `urlencode` filter.

Comment: I'm not sure where my responsibilities end between merely answering the original question directly and turning this answer into a perpetually relevant source of advice on security practices. I'm going to settle for a general disclaimer for now. Thanks for drawing my attention to this.

Comment: Thanks again. Hopefully though users will notice the age of this question, or at least look through the release notes when they see a deprecation warning or import error.

Comment: is is_safe_url outdated? I looked through the django documentation, didn't find anything to do with is_safe_url?

Comment: Yes, see @mlissner's comment. It's now `url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme`. I have updated the code. Thanks for raising this.